# Re-binding an ajaxForm after content re-loads with ajax (jQuery 1.4.2)

Tags: jquery, ajax, binding, dynamic-rebinding

I'm trying to figure out why this is a problem when using jQuery 1.4.2 and not 1.3.2.

This is my function:

```
function prepare_logo_upload() {
    $("#logo-upload-form").ajaxForm({
        //alert(responseText);                                       
        success: function(responseText) {
            //alert(responseText);                                          
            $('#profile .wrapper').html(responseText);
            prepare_logo_upload();
        }
    });
}
```

Every other live event works but can't use the .live() method because ajaxForm is a plugin. 
I have noticed this also for other types of binding (clicks) using the old form (re-binding after callback)

Can you tell me if it is a way of solving this?

This is a similar question, but due to my newbie reputation here, can't comment or ask a question there, so I'll ask a new one here. 
-> [jQuery: Bind ajaxForm to a form on a page loaded via .load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208880/jquery-bind-ajaxform-to-a-form-on-a-page-loaded-via-load)

Thank you!

EDIT: The "#profile .wrapper" contains the form, so my problem is in getting it re-binded with the events after it reloads.

Comment: Does `#profile` contain `#logo-upload-form`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about not mentioning it! It loads the form and replaces it, so there's my problem with re-binding it after it reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess but, something like this?

```
$("#logo-upload-form").live("submit", function () {
    return (function () {
        jQuery(this).ajaxForm({
            //alert(responseText);                                       
            success: function(responseText) {
                //alert(responseText);                                          
                $('#profile .wrapper').html(responseText);
                // recursion 
                return arguments.callee();
            }
        });
    }());
});
```

Completely untested, btw.

Comment: This is funny, it loads the whole page again in that .wrapper div

I don't think it works to attach the ajaxForm only when submitting, it needs to be attached on load.

Thanks for your try, though!